# Ошибки HTML на сайте на WordPress

Tags: html

Здравствуйте! Не подскажите в какой функции на сайте искать ошибку №13 строка 377 при проверке моего сайта http://upors.ru на валидаторе (https://validator.w3.org/ ) В коде страницы сайта это строка тоже 377. Сайт на WordPress. Таких ошибок, как эта,  много на разных сайтах WordPress

Comment: No space between attributes. Необходимо поставить пробел между href и title

Comment: Поставить пробел в какой функции? В тех, что в админке  сайта есть, то в них нет href и title вместе.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0aF9YgxOEiOdFh0eDd6UWVMMHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Это динамическая функция. Что за функция в сайте или хосте отвечает за образование этой №13 ошибки? Сколько ищу не могу найти.